# Global Interceptor for ws:outbound-gateway

Tags: spring-integration, spring-ws

Spring integration's ws:outbound-gateway has an interceptor and interceptors property which allows me to define a ClientInterceptor for an outbound springWS.

For inbound web services using springWS i can define a **global** interceptor in sws:interceptors. I use this to log all inbound requests into a database.

Is there a way to define an interceptor for **ALL** ws:outbound-gateway instances? I would like to log outbound info in a database for all web services.

Answer (score 0):

M-m-m. There is no such a direct high-level API on the matter.
Although I guess we would use the `WebServiceTemplate` injection as a point to accept the same instance everywhere. But it is injection anyway for many `ws:outbound-gateway`.

The `inbound` part is really based on the single entry point, e.g. `MessageDispatcherServlet`, but `outbound` has different  of them, so that's why there is no global access to them.

I suggest you some trick in one of your configuration class, anyway:

```
@Autowired
private List<AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway> outboundWsGateways;

@PostConstruct
public void setup() {
   for (AbstractWebServiceOutboundGateway gateway: this.outboundWsGateways) {
        gateway.setInterceptors(...);
   }

}
```